# How to get Particular cell value from Previous row to Current Row in Gridview ?? Winforms Devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I Have GridView and If I select any Item from 1st Column(Repository Item LooupEdit) remaining Columns fill automatically regarding to that particular Item Selected. Now in new row i need to get the 3rd cell/column value of previous row and perform some calculation and set in new row.? How to complete my task ? help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the GridView's GetRowCellValue method:

```
object Value = MyGridView.GetRowCellValue("ColumnName", MyGridView.FocusedRowHandle - 1);
```

See:

- [GetRowCellValue](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetRowCellValuetopic)
- [Obtaining and Setting Cell Values](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument753)